# javafx css background image , cannot resolve file path

Tags: css, javafx

I'm  trying to set the background of my scene using css . This is my css:

```
 #subscene{
-fx-background-image: url("file:C:\Users\willf\Documents\comps sci\NEA\logo.png");
 }
```

From this statement I get the error ("cannot resolve  file path") , I have no idea why ,becuase the file path is correct.
I've tried double slashes , single quotes etcc.. and nuttin works

Am I missing something here?

Comment: My guess, assuming the file exists at the given location, is that the space in the `comps sci` directory name causes the problem. URLs cannot have spaces. What happens if you replace that part with `comps%20sci`? Also, is your `logo.png` file supposed to be an embedded resource? If so, then you don't want to use an absolute URL as you are;  use a resource path instead (e.g. if the file is at the root of the classpath: `url(/logo.png)`).

Comment: No luck:( ,I tried a new file path without  a space )"file:C:\Users\willf\Pictures\leader.png") but I get the same error

Comment: Ok I'll have a look at resource paths

Comment: Use forward slashes: Try `file:///C:/Users/willf/Documents/comps%20sci/NEA/logo.png`.

Comment: Thanks alot that works , and taking out the 'file:' part  .(-fx-background-image: url("///C:/Users/willf/Documents/comps%20sci/NEA/logo.png");

Comment: Don't use `file:` or an absolute path to the `C:` drive, it isn't portable to other systems, follow the [css instruction guide provided by oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/css.htm#BEIBBBCI).

Comment: Glad it works for you, but as mentioned by jewelsea, in all likelihood you will want to avoid an absolute `file:` URL. If you need something portable, use a resource.